# jQuery $().each instead of $.each()

Tags: jquery, loops, each, typeerror

I am writing a plugin using the standard authoring pattern for jQuery, using methods to do different things with, and I'm running into a problem with .each().

I understand from the docs about the difference between `$.each()` and `$(selector).each()` yet I can't figure out how to overcome my problem...

In my code I have a method that returns an object which has been stored using `$(selector).data()` which I can run a $.each() on like so:

```
$.each($(selector).maps('getdetails'), function(key, value){/* stuff here */});
```

However, in the scope of jQuery chainability, this isn't how it should be, and I can't understand how to do it like this:

```
$(selector).maps('getdetails').each(function(key, value){/* stuff here */});
```

For chainability and ease of use for the user, the latter is preferable. Yet I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: $(selector).maps("getdetails").each is not a function
```

Here is the method in question from within the variable object:

```
getdetails: function(){
    return $(this).data('maps').details;
},
```

*(Yes, before you say it, I know this is incorrect JS, but as I said, it is correctly wrapped in a variable {} in my code.)*

Does anyone know how I can manipulate this object into a jQuery object that the latter `.each()` function will iterate over?

Comment: Is `$(this).data('maps').details` an array?

Comment: $(this).data('maps').details is an object of objects as key > value pairs. I have it returning the jQuery object type now after @zzzzBov's answer below, please see my comment on there though, as I'm still not getting desired results.

Comment: I think you're stuck with `$.each`. A jQuery instance object can only contain an array of values, but what you have is a set of key-value pairs. If you want to use `.each()`, you need an jQuery instance object which however cannot hold the keys but only the values.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Maybe I need to revisit how I store my data then ;o)

Comment: Ok, so instead of storing key > value pairs, each value is now an object stored in an array, and with the advice from here about $() wrapping my problem, it works as desired. Hats off again to Stack Overflow peeps!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `details` is an array, which is why `details.each` is not going to work. You'll need to convert `details` to a `jQuery.init` object (the map of jQueried objects), which is done simply by throwing it into the `jQuery` function:

```
return $( $(this).data('maps').details );
```

Comment: `details.each` does not work not because it's an array but because it's not a jQuery instance object. Your phrasing suggests that it would work if it weren't an array.

Comment: However, I now have a second problem. `$(this).data('maps').details` is an object of objects as key > value pairs. Doing the above returns me one object which is iterated over, therefore only having one iteration. How would I just return it's children?

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting the '#' or '.' to signify an id or class, respectively?